# Can't set relative width and height with nuxt-img - performance issue

Tags: image, nuxt.js

I am programming a website in nuxt and to optimize the images I use nuxt-img.

By optimizing the site with Google Page Speed I saw that the performance value penalizes me because it marks me that the images I use on the site do not have an explicit "height" and "width" tag (see photo).

I set the width and height of the images via the class in the css because they must have relative width and height (eg%, vw, vh) and the height and width property of nuxt-img only accepts "px".

Anyone know how to fix? I don't find anything in the documentation

[image]

I have the following

```html
<nuxt-img 
  id="imgl" 
  class="bn-img-left" 
  src="/team/TeamBW.webp" 
  loading="lazy" 
  sizes="sm:100vw md:50vw lg:100vw" 
  alt="Team Adapto bianco nero a sinsitra"
>
</nuxt-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read that one? https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img

This is how you define your images, you give it a value in `w` (pixels pretty much) or `vw`, then you can pass an aspect-ratio to it. But it's never fully responsive on both axes.

There are quite of articles on the web regarding that question: https://web.dev/learn/design/responsive-images/

That one is also interesting: https://jakearchibald.com/2022/img-aspect-ratio/

The idea is to provide various resolutions to the browser so that it can choose the closest one fitting the needs. Then, there will be some small differences caused by the weight difference (if an image fall in the middle of 2, size-wise).

Comment: Your answer is for normal html img tags, I'm running nuxt-img module, like this:

<nuxt-img id="imgl" class="bn-img-left" src="/team/TeamBW.webp" loading="lazy" sizes="sm:100vw md:50vw lg:100vw" alt="Team Adapto bianco nero a sinsitra"></nuxt-img>

(So i can't set % or vw width)

Comment: @Dimitri doesn't matter, the same applies here. The `sizes` prop does not generate the width? Hm, strange that should work.

Comment: The problem is that the dimensions are imposed with a class in the css. And google page speed gets mad because I don't put width and height properties in the <nuxt-img> tag. But this does not take on relative dimensions. My aim is to remove the error from google page speed and increase my performance score

Comment: You should have it set in HTM initially, so that you don't have any CLS. CSS will not help prevent that AFAIK. @Dimitri

Comment: okay ty, so the answer is that there is not a way to do relative value whit nuxt-img

Comment: @Dimitri same way as in vanilla HTML/JS basically. Nuxt (or it's module) have nothing to do here, this is how browsers work nowadays.